# Allowing Multiple Connection to project with local Database ? VB

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I've just build my first solution of my project that consist of a Local .mdf database & forms. However when i tried to access from different computers in a local network, only one is able to run the project at a time. The others computer failed & displayed a timeout error. I would just like to have an explanation why it happened? Why isn't my .mdf allowing multiple computers to access it?

p.s It works great when only one computer is running/using the project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in using a real SQL-server, which runs as a service on a server to ensure multiple users can connect with ease.

Comment: Thanks, i've managed to set up a SQL Server & works fine now . My question is why does it require an SQL server to do the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Just curious is it possible it didnt work because they don't have sql server installed on there machine and the machine therefor doesnt know how to interact with the .mdf file?

Simultaneous or direct access to Database files is a very bad practice or simply impossible.

Use proper DBMS tools to access the data.

And yes - its possible to access Web site project for demo.

srces: [Multiple connections on a single .mdf database (ASP.net) SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972238/multiple-connections-on-a-single-mdf-database-asp-net-sql-server)

answered Jan 23 '12 at 13:20

Oleg Dok
10.2k1521